# SharePoint 2013 BCS and SQL Views

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sql-server, bcs, external-content-type, external-data

I have setup my SharePoint 2013 publishing site with BCS and Secure Store so that users can access multiple external lists within the site and if they have the correct permissions setup in Secure Store then they can edit the ECT's and it will update the SQL tables.

Here is my question though. If I create a 'View' in SQL and that view contains multiple columns from different tables within the database, can I create an ECT with that view, create an external list with the view, and have users modify it, and it will then update all the base tables within the View? I had thought I read somewhere that you cannot update multiple base tables using BCS, but can't seem to get a good answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedures for performing CRUD operations on data related to different tables. Check [this for more](http://spsamer.com/2012/05/08/implementing-ects-in-spd-using-stored-procedures/) information.